# getJSON JavaScript function returns undefined object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

This is my **JavaScript** code:

```
// action when item file is clicked
$("li span.file").click(function(){

    // get the ID
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));

    $.getJSON('BomItemToJSON', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var id = item.id;
            var description = item.description;

            formObject = document.forms['itemForm'];
            formObject.elements['itemId'].value = id;
            formObject.elements['itemDescription'].value = description;
        });
    });

});
```

This is a part of my **servlet**:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        utx.begin();

        BomHandling bh = new BomHandling(em, utx);

        BomItem item = bh.getBomItem(63788);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(item);

        System.out.println("Json: " + json);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        utx.commit();
    }
```

It returns:

```
Json: {"itemId":63788,"modules":[],"deprecated":false,"partNumber":"SG-XPCIE8SAS-E-Z","description":"4 GB Memory Expansion (2 x 2GB) low-profile FBDIMMs, Gen 2, 1.8 V, for Sun SPARC Enterprise, RoHS 6. (For Factory Integration Only)","quantity":0,"unitPriceDollar":"$350.00","discount":"10%","totalDollar":"$0.00","itemClass":"Server","itemType":"HW","vendor":"Sun"}
```

From the console log I know that this servlet is called:

```
[09:22:11.633] GET http://localhost:8084/xxx/BomItemToJSON [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 80ms]
```

This is my **form**:

```
<div id="itemdetail">
    <form name="itemForm">
        ID: <input type="text" name="itemId" value="" size="100"></input>
        Description: <input type="text" name="itemDescription" value="" size="100"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I insert the itemId and the description from the JSON object into my form? Right now it is always 'undefined'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the each. Your JSON is only a single object, not an array.

Your code should be like this I think:

```
// action when item file is clicked
$("li span.file").click(function(){

    // get the ID
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));

    $.getJSON('BomItemToJSON', function(data) {
        alert('entered getJSON()');
        var id = data.itemId;
        var description = data.description;

        alert('description: ' + description);

        formObject = document.forms['itemForm'];
        formObject.elements['itemId'].value = id;
        formObject.elements['itemDescription'].value = description;

        alert('done with javascript');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

a JSON object should be wrapped inside brackets: `{ Json: { ... } }` 
if you try to validate your json with [jsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) you can notice the error

Comment: I thought about this, not clear on whether the OP is saying "this is my Json:" or that's part of the code.

Comment: :) before starting to see code errors on code that deals with JSON, I usually double-check the structure returned

Comment: Looking at his servlet code, it looks like that's the output of this line: `System.out.println("Json: " + json);` so probably not part of the code.